# NServiceBus not deserializing message

Tags: json.net, nservicebus

I have a simple sender/receiver setup with NServiceBus

Both sides have:

```
Newtonsoft.Json (11.0.2)
Newtonsoft.Bson (1.0.1)
NServiceBus.Newtonsoft.Json (2.1.0)
```

I am getting a the error shown below when NServiceBus tries to deserialize the message

```
2018-10-01 14:39:47.383 ERROR NServiceBus.RecoverabilityExecutor Moving message 'a687555c-d4be-49dc-acba-a96c00e0d261' to the error queue 'error' because processing failed due to an exception:
NServiceBus.MessageDeserializationException: An error occurred while attempting to extract logical messages from incoming physical message a687555c-d4be-49dc-acba-a96c00e0d261 ---> System.Exception: Could not find metadata for 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.
Ensure the following:
1. 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' is included in initial scanning. 
2. 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' implements either 'IMessage', 'IEvent' or 'ICommand' or alternatively, if you don't want to implement an interface, you can use 'Unobtrusive Mode'.
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Messages.MessageMetadataRegistry.GetMessageMetadata(Type messageType)
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.LogicalMessageFactory.Create(Type messageType, Object message)
   at NServiceBus.DeserializeLogicalMessagesConnector.Extract(IncomingMessage physicalMessage)
   at NServiceBus.DeserializeLogicalMessagesConnector.ExtractWithExceptionHandling(IncomingMessage message)
```

I am not really sure what to do to resolve this as its an issue within Newtonsoft by the look of it

Has anyone else encountered this?

Paul

Comment: Do you use conventions or unobtrusive mode for your message types (maybe in one endpoint and not the other)? Can you post sender/receiver endpoint configs?

Comment: Will post configs when I get back to computer. All my messages inherit from ICommand and I use the same config both sides

Comment: Is this still an issue for you, Paul?